# What determines "flexion" vs "extension" terminology?

Tags: terminology, anatomy

Why is lifting your arm (or leg) in front of your body (like a Nazi salute, rather than swinging it behind your back like a martial arts shoulder pin) called flexion rather than extension? And why is bending your head (or foot) down, rather than lifting it back, also termed flexion rather than extension?

Is there a consistent or official rule for identifying the direction named "flexion" in all joints (including shoulder, hip, elbow, spinal vertebrae, foot, etc)? The terminology seems simple for joints like the elbow (bending versus straightening), but for the shoulder joint it isn't obvious what the meaning of  *flexion* versus *extension* is derived from. (If "flexion" means reducing the angle, then how do you identify which two vectors to measure between for a ball and socket joint?) Is flexion always the direction in which the joint is able to travel farther, when starting from "standard anatomical position"? Alternatively, are the choices just an arbitrary historical convention (traced to whom)?